# JSON data UITableView to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

iam not very good at coding,i have a serious problem in my code,i want to show my json data from one talbe to another,forexample:in the first tableview i would like to show the Students" name, and after the name is clicked, it shall jump to next tableview and show the course that this student had been chosen(one student may have more than one course),so how can i do it? Here is mycode in the first tableview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this     view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.Title = @"選擇類別";
//    classify = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"時尚類",@"飲食類",@"娛樂類",@"文創類",   nil];
//    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataList" ofType:@"plist"];
//    classify_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile : path];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/store.php"];
NSData *jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;

classify_ = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:
        NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
 return 1;
 }

//table cell count
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.classify count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 cell.textLabel.text = [[self.classify objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]   objectForKey:@"classify"];

return cell;


}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Second"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    //NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController]   objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setSecondClassify:[self.classify objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
}
```

Comment: Are you from Taiwan or Hong Kong?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with JSON, by the way.  Once your data is in the `classify` array it could come from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

tableView1.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];    
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *item = [displayItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:item];
    } 
}
```

tableView2.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
```

tableView2.m:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.detailItem) {
       itemID = self.detailItem;
       [self getCourse];
    }
}

- (void)getCourse{

      NSString *code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@", itemID];
      NSData *postData = [code dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
      NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/getUser.php"];

      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
      [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
      [request setHTTPBody:postData];

      NSURLResponse *response;
      NSError *error;
      NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

      allCourseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

      NSDictionary *item = [allCourseArray objectAtIndex:0];

      NSString *courseName = [item objectForKey:@"courseName"];
      NSString *courseCode = [item objectForKey:@"courseCode"];
}
```

Comment: I still doesn't know how to get the data on the second tableview, how can i retrieve the data from the first tableview index and display the course data on the second tableview cell.text?

Comment: 你看一下這個網頁:　1. [link](http://www.cnblogs.com/lightbluewind/archive/2011/12/07/2279839.html) 2. [link](http://www.cnblogs.com/lightbluewind/archive/2011/12/07/2279856.html)